# iOS IBAction method never gets called

Tags: ios, segue, ibaction, cs193p

I'm working through the CS193p Stanford iOS course and am nearly done with Assignment 3 - in which I convert the graphing calculator to a universal app for iPad as well. The app draws a graph when a program (e.g. "x + 3") is entered into the calculator and then the user presses a  Graph button. On the iPhone, I simply segued when the Graph button was pressed, but in the iPad, I have a UISplitViewController that I set up a target action from the Graph button:

```
- (IBAction)ipadGraphPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ([self splitViewGraphViewController]) {
        [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] setProgram:self.brain.program];
    }
}
```

This calls `setProgram:` in the GraphViewController, which then calls `setNeedsDisplay:` on the GraphView and should draw the graph.

For comparison, here is the segue method that works on iPhone:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController setProgram:self.brain.program];
}
```

I am very sure that the connection is established between the button and its action method, but when I run the app, this action method never gets called when the button is pressed. Is there anything else to check for to ensure the method gets called?

Comment: If the action method does not get called when the button is pressed, then one way or another the `IBAction` is not bound to the button correctly.  Are you sure you connected the `IBAction` to the 'Touch up inside' event, and that you are creating your view controller in a way that allows the connections to be autowired for you at instantiation time?

Comment: I'm positive the Touch Up Inside event is connected. As for the view controller setup, I'm not so sure. The iPhone segue works by setting the GraphViewController program property, and so I did the exact same thing in the action method. I assumed that would work the same.

Comment: First recheck that button has its action connected to ipadGraphPressed. Then add NSLog(@"%@",sender); inside the method, press the button and see whether the button is working or not.

Comment: Yes, it is connected, and no that log never showed up in console after pressing the button.

Comment: I just tried adding a new UIButton to the storyboard, and it does not appear when I run the app in sim. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with the storyboard itself. Any guesses on what to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was nothing wrong with my code, per se. After fiddling with the storyboard, I noticed that even if I added new buttons to the master view, they never showed up when the application launched. I tried changing the name of the storyboard from `iPad.storyboard` to `iPad_1.storyboard`, and then my changes showed up, but none of my rotation code was in effect. My solution to this whole mess was to backtrack to a previous version of the app right before I added the new storyboard. I re-added an iPad storyboard and was able to make all the correct connections.

To confirm this, a friend of mine checked out the project on Github and reported that while I was not able to call the IBAction method, it worked perfectly fine for him. I believe there was something messed up with my local storyboard settings, and this was preventing the application from working correctly. My takeaway from this is to be careful with naming and renaming storyboard files, especially when dealing with version control.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I connected everything properly on my IBOutlets and IBActions. What's causing the problem is a transparent view on top of the buttons that's blocking the touches.

After I resized the view so that it won't block the buttons underneath it, it solved my problem.